# JFreechart stop unzoom when drag left

Tags: jfreechart

How do I stop JFreechart from unzooming when I drag left?

thxs.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by drag left? is it the normal behavior of unzooming you want to override?

Comment: do you want to disable unzooming entirely, or you only want to disable that behavior initiated by the mouse dragging? If you could provide more info I could help perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made an assumption (based on your short question) that you want to disable the "zoom restore" feature when invoked by the mouse being dragged to the left.

If so, you simply need to override the `restoreAutobounds()` method like this:

```
JFreeChart chart = /* create your chart here*/

// add the chart to the panel and override 
// the zoom restore behavior

chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart){

    @Override
    public void restoreAutoBounds(){
        // Do nothing
    }           
};
```

Or, event better is to extend the `ChartPanel` object and override it there.

NOTE: the zoom out feature will still be available from the context menu of the chart so the user still has meaningful ways to zoom out

Comment: Basically I want to use the ESC key to unzoom...and disable the zoom restore...thats should be possible right?

Comment: In that case you'd have to have some logic in your restoreAutoBounds() override. For example you'd have to intercept the ESC key and call restoreAutoBounds() while flagging that it has to actually restore it, then just call super.restoreAutoBounds(), in the case of mouse dragging do nothing in your override.

Comment: It might be that the ChartPanel object does not have focus. My experience with JFreeChart is limited to SWT. I've never used it in SWING or AWT. Here is a link I found where the focus problem is mentioned: http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22921